# CoreData NSPredicate with nested to-many and to-one relations

Tags: swift, core-data, nspredicate, predicate

I have a question about using NSPredicates with nested entities in CoreData. My model has both to-many and to-one relations.  I'm fetching an array of CachedProvider, each with an array of CachedBuilding, and each building with a City (nested to-one relation). I'm attaching some images of my models:

- [CachedProvider](https://gyazo.com/375ac0223073fdff718327c980c1646b)
- [CachedBuilding](https://gyazo.com/641eb9dbfb21ca22e270974e74d43c57)
- [CachedCity](https://gyazo.com/affc4682788f50fcb8e45124ee707822)

I'm wondering how can I filter my data based on the City name property? I've tried quite a few examples found in stackoverflow but none seems to work for me.

Filter by building name: This works

```
let predicate = NSPredicate(
  format: "SUBQUERY(buildings, $building, $building.name_romaji CONTAINS [cd] %@).@count > 0", 
  "building a"
)
@FetchRequest(sortDescriptors: [], predicate: predicate) var providers: FetchedResults<CachedProvider>
```

```
let predicate = NSPredicate(format: "ANY buildings.name_romaji CONTAINS [cd] %@", "building a")
@FetchRequest(sortDescriptors: [], predicate: predicate) var providers: FetchedResults<CachedProvider>
```

However, when I try filtering by the nested to-one relation (City name), this no longer works, i get an empty array of results back.

```
let predicate = NSPredicate(
  format: "SUBQUERY(buildings, $building, $building.city.name_romaji CONTAINS [cd] %@).@count > 0", 
  "kyoto"
)
@FetchRequest(sortDescriptors: [], predicate: predicate) var providers: FetchedResults<CachedProvider>
```

```
let predicate = NSPredicate(format: "ANY buildings.city.name_romaji CONTAINS [cd] %@", "kyoto")
@FetchRequest(sortDescriptors: [], predicate: predicate) var providers: FetchedResults<CachedProvider>
```

I've also attempted using a block predicate but as i understand they are not supported in CoreData.

Is there anything I can do to improve my predicate? I'm not exactly sure i understand why the query by city name fails.

Comment: Looks like the error is happening because the City entity is optional. I was able to make it work with a predicate such as this one: 

`NSPredicate(format: "ANY buildings.city != nil AND ANY buildings.city.name_romaji != nil AND ANY buildings.city.name_romaji CONTAINS [cd] %@", "tokyo")`

Comment: Is this an answer, has the problem been resolved?

Comment: yes, i've fixed the issue by first checking for non-null values

Comment: Then either post the solution as a proper answer or remove the question.

Answer (score 2):

The error happens because the City entity is optional. It will work with a predicate such as this one:

```
NSPredicate(
  format: "ANY buildings.city != nil AND ANY buildings.city.name_romaji != nil AND ANY buildings.city.name_romaji CONTAINS [cd] %@", 
 "tokyo"
)
```